# pkcs11-tool does not see card which is identified by pcsc

Tags: pkcs#11, opensc

I am using a REINER SCT cyberJack RFID standard card reader and an estonian ID card.
pcsc_scan correctly identifies the card:

```
$ pcsc_scan
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.5.2 (c) 2001-2017, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: REINER SCT cyberJack RFID standard (9084002233) 00 00

Wed Mar 13 14:02:39 2019
 Reader 0: REINER SCT cyberJack RFID standard (9084002233) 00 00
  Card state: Card inserted, 
  ATR: 3B DB 96 00 80 B1 FE 45 1F 83 00 12 23 3F 53 65 49 44 0F 90 00 F1

ATR: 3B DB 96 00 80 B1 FE 45 1F 83 00 12 23 3F 53 65 49 44 0F 90 00 F1
+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention
+ T0 = DB, Y(1): 1101, K: 11 (historical bytes)
  TA(1) = 96 --> Fi=512, Di=32, 16 cycles/ETU
    250000 bits/s at 4 MHz, fMax for Fi = 5 MHz => 312500 bits/s
  TC(1) = 00 --> Extra guard time: 0
  TD(1) = 80 --> Y(i+1) = 1000, Protocol T = 0 
-----
  TD(2) = B1 --> Y(i+1) = 1011, Protocol T = 1 
-----
  TA(3) = FE --> IFSC: 254
  TB(3) = 45 --> Block Waiting Integer: 4 - Character Waiting Integer: 5
  TD(3) = 1F --> Y(i+1) = 0001, Protocol T = 15 - Global interface bytes following 
-----
  TA(4) = 83 --> Clock stop: state H - Class accepted by the card: (3G) A 5V B 3V 
+ Historical bytes: 00 12 23 3F 53 65 49 44 0F 90 00
  Category indicator byte: 00 (compact TLV data object)
    Tag: 1, len: 2 (country code, ISO 3166-1)
      Country code: 23 3F
    Tag: 5, len: 3 (card issuer's data)
      Card issuer data: 65 49 44
    Mandatory status indicator (3 last bytes)
      LCS (life card cycle): 0F (unknown)
      SW: 9000 (Normal processing.)
+ TCK = F1 (correct checksum)

Possibly identified card (using /home/mag/.cache/smartcard_list.txt):
3B DB 96 00 80 B1 FE 45 1F 83 00 12 23 3F 53 65 49 44 0F 90 00 F1
    Estonia ID-card (eID)
    https://id.ee
```

however pkcs11-tool does not see the card:

```
$ pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so -L
Available slots:
Slot 0 (0x0): REINER SCT cyberJack RFID standard (9084002233) 00 00
  (empty)
```

What can be the cause of the problem? What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the toolchain of the estonian card is not compatible with pkcs-11. However the `chrome-token-signing` package contains the needed code at least for authentication to their service both for chromium and firefox, and the `qdigidoc4` package contains a tool to create and check signed/encrypted documents.
Their repo is here:

```
deb https://installer.id.ee/media/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

Another issue I have encountered that my cert is said to be invalid. That was because the certificate won't get enabled right away when you receive your ID.